# How i can exchange the erc20 with ether

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, erc-20

i want to make crypto to crypto smart contract where i need to sell erc20 token and on buyer side i need to calculate the price which i have to send to seller and i have a price of token can you please describe the calculation.below is my function.

```
function buyToken(uint256 _tradeId, address token, uint256 _quantity, uint256 _tokenPrice) external {

   uint256 quantity = _quantity * (10 ** ERC20Interface(token).decimals);
   uint256 amount = quantity * _tokenPrice;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103703/discussion-on-question-by-love-chawda-how-i-can-exchange-the-erc20-with-ether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resolution of ether is 18 decimals, but the resolution of an ERC20-token is not necessarily the same, you can use this:

```
uint256 amount;
uint8 decimals = ERC20Interface(token).decimals;
if (decimals > 18)
    amount = _quantity * _tokenPrice / 10 ** (decimals - 18);
else
    amount = _quantity * _tokenPrice * 10 ** (18 - decimals);
```

Be sure to replace the `*` operations with `SafeMath.mul`.